# AOSP - where does default launcher look for apps to display

Tags: android, android-source

I'm building a kiosk type device on generic Android-TV hardware.  I was given an Android Open Source firmware build from the manufacturer that works with the chipset. My goal is to install my app into the system image so all the devices I flash will have it automatically installed.  (I can't build the firmware myself since there were proprietary drivers required that I don't have access to).

To install my app, I mounted the system.img, manually copied my .apk to the /system/priv-app directory and added my package to the /etc/permissions/privapp-permissions-platform.xml file.

What I can't seem to find is where the Launcher looks for apps to display on the home screen.  Is there a directory somewhere in the system image where I should add a link to my .apk?  Or an XML file I need to edit?